# How to load image via URL into BottomNavigationView menu item icon

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu, bottomnavigationview

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667798/10733439) answer, But it showed up like this

[image]

and this is my code

```
String imageUrl = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYjRjMTA5YjAtMTNjYy00M2E0LTk0YWEtMjE4ZDI3MTdlZmZjXkEyXkFqcGdeQTNwaW5nZXN0._V1_.jpg";
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(
                        RequestOptions.circleCropTransform().placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                )
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Drawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource);
                        mBinding.bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_my_profile).setIcon(bitmapDrawable);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    }
                });
```

> note: my emulator is Android 7 and I tried it on a phone that contains Android 11, but it doesn't work

How can I create this feature?

[image]

> note: I preferred `Java`, if it `kotlin` no problem

Comment: [Accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861254/how-to-change-a-specific-icon-image-from-bottom-navigation-view) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you find how to load it from a url dear?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the proposed solutions and none of them worked that great. So here is how I solved the issue - by going straight for the icon view.
Simply access the icon view - which is an image view - and let your favorit image SDK do the rest. This also bypasses the tint and renders the bitmap in full color.

```
        final BottomNavigationMenuView mbottomNavigationMenuView =
                (BottomNavigationMenuView) binding.navView.getChildAt(0);
        final BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView)mbottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(3);
        final ImageView profileItemIcon = (ImageView) ((ViewGroup)itemView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1);
        Picasso.get().load(sharedPreferences.getString(RestManager.LOGO, null)).transform(PicassoHelper.profileImageTransformation).fit()
                .centerCrop().transform(PicassoHelper.borderedProfileImageTransformation)
                .into(profileItemIcon);
```